# Out Of Memory Error even Heap Memory is not Completely Use

Tags: java, jvm, glassfish, heap-memory, glassfish-4

I am facing

> Out of memory error in java heap space

I am using glassfish server for deployment of my maven based application, and Java JDK is 1.7.
I have configured my glassfish server domain.xml as MaxPermSize is 512M and Xmx is 1024M , as mentioned in snap 1, I am confused because my glassfish not utilizing complete 1GB of heap size as it having , its just consumed max heap 300m but its through above error and stooped everything.
how can I resolve this issue? its occurs two times a day.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You probably have a memory leak, e.g. not closing opened resources, like files

Comment: The graph in the second picture shows that it only has 300mb of heap tho. Double check if it actually is using your config or it overwrites it.

Comment: @WesleyDeKeirsmaeker, It shows Xmx:1024 in its JVM Arguments.

Answer (score 0):

-XX:NewRatio=2 means that:

```
old generation size : young generation size = 2:1
```

So the young generation size is 1024/3 = 341M. 
It means that:

```
Eden size + 2*Survivor = 341M
```

The Eden size is about 300M.

You should set Xmx bigger.